# Newbie - Android coding issue of button

Tags: android, button

I placed a button and set its id to `@+id/ourButton`.

Then on the **MainActivity.java**:

```
Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ourButton);
```

It looks `R.id.ourButton` is undeclared or not existing.

Comment: Refresh or Clean your project

Comment: try to clean you project. and check the `R` in your imports.

Comment: can you plz post your xml layout and MainActivity code

Comment: and make sure you are importing `your_package_name.R` class not `android.R` class...

Comment: Check your imports for R. It should be as @GopalRao mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You can either do a clean on your project or delete your R file, which will then be regenerated.

Answer (score 0):

1. Clean your project or restart the eclipse.
2. Look to the imports, the R imported maybe is not correct.
3. If anything is wrong in your layouts, new updates aren't added to the R file. Look at the errors panel, and possibly to a clean rebuild to see what errors are popping up.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted the R.java. The also did a Clean... Exit Eclipse and the R.java still missing.

Comment: Check out the error log in the "Problems" tab in eclipse.